# Jira: query to get users who moved ticket from status A to B

Tags: jira, jql

Trying to write q query or dashboard to get an idea of how many people have moved tickets from status A to B I.e.

USER 1 : 18
User 2 : 2

Etc

Can this be achieved in jira?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following jql if you have scriptrunner;

```
status changed FROM open TO closed and issueFunction in aggregateExpression("Users", "assignee.countBy{it}")
```